# Query Builder Plugin for Angular 4

Tags: angular, npm, query-builder

I need a query builder plugin for Angular 4 to build nested queries which I can use in my project.

I came across some of them like:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-query-builder (Requires Angular4+ )
http://mfauveau.github.io/angular-query-builder/ (For AngularJS)
http://niklr.github.io/angular-query-builder/ (For Angular JS).

The problem is that they either require Angular4+ or they are for AngularJS. Since my project is in Angular 4, I am not entire sure if using any one of them will help me or it might break my application due to Angular version dependency mismatch. Since it is an enterprise project, I can't afford to upgrade the Angular version to 6 since it has many third party plugins based on Angular 4 and might also cause some problems in build and deployment pipeline.

I want to know if there exists a query builder plugin for Angular 4 or I can use any one of the above mentioned plugins without causing any regression due to Angular version mismatch.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic here. However, you may find better luck [SoftwareRecs.SE](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Comment: The only way to make sure is to use it. I would suggest to check the tags dropdown in github and most likely there will be version 4 .  You can install by doing `npm install your-lib@version --save

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the first one. 
It works for

```
@angular/common : >=4.0.0
@angular/core : >=4.0.0
```

https://zebzhao.github.io/Angular-QueryBuilder/dependencies.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one as well [Advanced Query Builder](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-querybuilder)